# Messed up audio port leaves sound only in the right earbud/headphone

Tags: audio, speakers

**tldr;** I yanked headphones out at the wrong angle, and messed something up in the 3.5mm audio port. Now sound only plays through the right side of any pair of headphones.

I had carelessly left my (cheap, thankfully) headphones hanging on my chair while plugged in. When I pulled the chair out the headphones were yanked sharply, but I didn't give a second thought afterwards.

When I pulled the headphones out later, the 3.5mm jack was bent, and sound came only from the right side. I tested a pair of earbuds, and they only played sound on the right side. These earbuds work on different computers, so it is not a problem with them. I have another audio port on the back of my computer, but it is inconvenient to turn my PC around every time I need audio. **Note:** The broken port is not directly connected to my motherboard, and it has a wire running between the port and the mobo.

Is there any way for me to fix this messed up port? If not, how can I replace this port as painlessly as possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you've pulled the audio connector off circuit board/connecting wires and disconnected the left audio channel.

Unless you are handy with a soldering iron it probably isn't worth fixing. Instead I would just purchase a cheap USB sound card like so, they can normally be [purchased for about $1-$20](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=usb%20sound%20adapter&biw=1357&bih=891&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY7uvy2-XPAhUGlZQKHWmTC0MQ_AUIBSgA&dpr=1#q=usb%20sound%20adapter&tbm=shop):

[image: USB sound card]

Comment: Is it worth popping open my case to check if I can reconnect anything?

Comment: Perhaps, but it's probably a sealed unit that's hard to get at unless you open it all up and glue it back together

Comment: I built the PC from scratch, and have easy access to the motherboard connector pins

Comment: @ID3K Yes, you can buy a new connector and replace it. If you want to risk the life of your motherboard,